# JSON string will not deserialize into the type specified

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-webassembly

I have the following bit of code whihc sends a Http POST request to the server.  The server reurns a 400 Bad request response along with a error object in the form of Json:

```
namespace MyApp.Shared.Dtos.Response
{
    public class ErrorItem
    {
        public string Message { get; set; }
        public string Tag { get; set; }
    }

    public class ErrorDto
    {
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public List<ErrorItem> Errors { get; set; } = new();
    }
}

namespace Accounting.Web.Services
{
    public interface IHttpService
    {
        Task<T> Get<T>(string uri);
        Task<T> Post<T>(string uri, object value, bool addBearerToken = false);
        public ErrorDto Error { get; set; }
    }

    public class HttpService: IHttpService
    {
        private HttpClient _httpClient;
        public ErrorDto Error { get; set; }

        public HttpService(HttpClient httpClient)
        {
            _httpClient = httpClient;
            _stateService = stateService;
        }

        public async Task<T> Post<T>(string uri, object value)
        {
            var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, uri);
            request.Content = new StringContent(JsonSerializer.Serialize(value), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            return await sendRequest<T>(request, addBearerToken);
        }

        private async Task<T> sendRequest<T>(HttpRequestMessage request)
        {
            using var response = await _httpClient.SendAsync(request);
            
            if (response.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.BadRequest)
            {
                var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                Error = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<ErrorDto>(result);
                //..
            } 
            else
            {
                //..
            }            
        }
    }
}
```

The result correctly recieves the following response from the server as a JSON string:

{"title":"Username or password is incorrect","errors":[]}

And I can confirm by inspecting var result, it has the above value.

However, It doesn't seem deserialize into the ErrorDto class as one would expect it to:
Error = JsonSerializer.Deserialize(result);

But I simply cannot see any problems with the code, it looks like it should be working.

*** UPDATE ***

My server API code returrns the JSOn using the same DTO class (It's a shared class) using the following code:

```
[HttpPost("authenticate")]
public ActionResult Authenticate(AuthenticateRequest loginRequest)
{
    var auth = _userService.Authenticate(loginRequest);
    ErrorDto error = new()
    {
        Title = "Username or password is incorrect"
    };
    if (auth.user == null || auth.token == null)
    {
        return BadRequest(error);
    }
    return Ok(auth.user.ConvertToDto(auth.token));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default `System.Text.Json` [is case-sensitive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/character-casing#case-insensitive-property-matching). There are multiple options to handle this, for example by providing corresponding `JsonSerializerOptions`:

```cs
var json = @"{""title"":""Username or password is incorrect"",""errors"":[]}";
var errorDto = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<ErrorDto>(json, new JsonSerializerOptions
{
    PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true
});
```

Or marking properties with corresponding `JsonPropertyNameAttribute`:

```
public class ErrorItem
{
    [JsonPropertyName("message")]
    public string Message { get; set; }
    [JsonPropertyName("tag")]
    public string Tag { get; set; }
}

public class ErrorDto
{
    [JsonPropertyName("title")]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("errors")]
    public List<ErrorItem> Errors { get; set; } = new();
}
```

**UPD**

From [How to customize property names and values with System.Text.Json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/customize-properties?pivots=dotnet-7-0) doc:

> **Note**
> The web default is camel case.

If you want to switch from camel case to the naming policy used for DTOs you can do the following:

```cs
builder.Services.AddControllers()
    .AddJsonOptions(opts => opts.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = null);
```

Comment: Ah of course, but I can't understand why it's being returned as lower string in the first place from my server API which serialises the same class for the response.  I've updated my question to to include the server API code

Comment: @MusaffarPatel cause as [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/customize-properties?pivots=dotnet-7-0) specifies _"The web default is camel case."_